# MagicSuggest fails with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, magicsuggest

I am using MagicSuggest to autocomplete tags.
This code works perfect:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ms3 = $('#ms3').magicSuggest({
            data: [{id:12,name:'php'},{id:1212,name:'java'},{id:112,name:'python'},{id:125,name:'html'},{id:172,name:'css'}]
        });
    });
```

But this one doesn't:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ms3 = $('#ms3').magicSuggest({
            data:'data.php'
        });
    });
```

php:

```
    <?php
          echo "[{id:12,name:'php'},{id:1212,name:'java'},{id:112,name:'python'},{id:125,name:'html'},{id:172,name:'css'}]";
    ?>
```

P.S. This works when data:'data.json' with json data inside.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488053/magicsuggest-dynamic-ajax-source

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that the problem could be the fact that the php file returns wrong mime type.
Try adding this at the top of your `data.php` file
`header('Content-type: application/json');`

So your `data.php` file would look like

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo "[{id:12,name:'php'},{id:1212,name:'java'},{id:112,name:'python'},{id:125,name:'html'},{id:172,name:'css'}]";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSON specification not presend single quotes - you must change to double quotes

better you can use json_encode function

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    array('id'=>12, 'name'=> 'php')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you...

```
<?php
    $mydata = "[{id:12,name:'php'},{id:1212,name:'java'},{id:112,name:'python'},{id:125,name:'html'},{id:172,name:'css'}]";
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ms3 = $('#ms3').magicSuggest({
        data: <?php echo$mydata;?>
    });
});
```

That way you can populate `$mydata` with data from a database query etc.

**OR**

Try the follwing in your `data.php` file;

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo "[{id:12,name:'php'},{id:1212,name:'java'},{id:112,name:'python'},{id:125,name:'html'},{id:172,name:'css'}]";
 ?>
```

Comment: `data: <?php echo$mydata;?>` Even when this query is hundreds of rows?